# how to fix the css padding in this situation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to css the share button with Font-Awesome icon. I use padding to create each icon's width. However, when it reach to the end of the div, it cut off like below's image. Why don't I use share-icon image instead? I though image will slow down the page loading.I had tried margin, not working. White-space:nowrap will penetrate the div and give me one line. Help, please.

[image]

```css
.share_buttons{
     margin-top: 9px;
  line-height: 4.4;
 }
 
  .share_buttons a{
   color:#fefefe;
   background:#7f98cf;
      padding: 17px 15px 6px 15px;
      -moz-border-radius: 50px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
      border-radius: 12px;
   margin-left:4px;
   margin-bottom:90px; 
   text-decoration:none; 
   text-align: center;
   cursor:pointer; 
   
  }
  .share_buttons a#facebook{
   background:#3b4ca4;
  }
  .share_buttons a#plus_share{
   background:#5976B5;
   
  }
  .share_buttons a#twitter{
   background:#73c6f1;
  }
  .share_buttons a#google_plus{
   background:#cb0000;
  }
  .share_buttons a#tumblr{
   background:#386082;
  }
  .share_buttons a#reddit{
   background:#c1c1c1;
   color:#333;
  }
  .share_buttons a#linkedin{
   background:#00649e;
  }
  .share_buttons a#pinterest{
   background:#e30000;
  }
  .share_buttons a#stumbleupon{
   background:#eb4924;
  }
  .share_buttons a#envelope{
   background:#65c093;
  }
```

```html
<div class="share_buttons" id="share_buttons_about">
  
  <!-- Facebook -->
  <a id="facebook" href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x">&nbspTell your friends</i></a>
  <!-- Twitter -->
  <a id="twitter" href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
 
  <!-- Google+ -->
  <a id="google_plus" href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-2x"></i></a>
  <!-- tublr -->
  <a id="tumblr"  href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-tumblr fa-2x"></i></a> 
 
  <!-- LinkedIn -->
  <a id="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x"></i></a>
  <!-- Pinterest -->
  <a id="pinterest"  href="javascript:void((function()%7Bvar%20e=document.createElement('script');e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');e.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');e.setAttribute('src','http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e)%7D)());"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p fa-2x"></i></a>
  <!-- StumbleUpon-->
  <a id="stumbleupon" href="" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-stumbleupon fa-2x"></i></a>
  <!-- Email -->
  <a id="envelope"  href=""><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x"></i></a>
  </div><!--share_buttons-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try displaying your buttons as `inline-block`. Right now, they are rendered as `inline`, which means they do not have their own box model and can get broken up into multiple lines.

With `inline-block`, elements are still displayed in line, side-by-side, but they also have the box model of a `block` element.

```
.share_buttons a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: doesnt fix the issue - just tried it in a fiddle :(

Comment: In fiddle not working, but actually in my case, it works, thanks both of your time. Appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Add `float:left;` to the `.share_buttons a{}` css.

And to keep on one line add a fixed width to the container div `width:608px;` to `.share_buttons`

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b9qr9uab/1/

Comment: Thanks for your time. Your example is great, but in my case, I could not put float:left. Thanks for your time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like it would be an issue because of the width of the items not being set. So it doesn't know where to break correctly as it doesn't know the width of the item.
I fixed this by explicitly setting the widths and then because the facebook is wider I have set the width within the ID selector. Not perfect but it works.
You also have a large padding underneath that causes it to push down the items so I brought it down to 20px rather than 90px.

```
.share_buttons{
    //margin-top: 9px;
    //line-height: 4.4;
    font-size: 12px;
}

    .share_buttons a{
        display: inline-block;   
        width: 32px;
        color:#fefefe;
        background:#7f98cf;
        padding: 6px 15px;
        -moz-border-radius: 50px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
        border-radius: 12px;
        margin-left:4px;
        margin-bottom:20px; 
        text-decoration:none;   
        text-align: center;
        cursor:pointer; 

    }
    .share_buttons a#facebook{
        background:#3b4ca4;
        width: 200px;
    }
    .share_buttons a#plus_share{
        background:#5976B5;

    }
    .share_buttons a#twitter{
        background:#73c6f1;
    }
    .share_buttons a#google_plus{
        background:#cb0000;
    }
    .share_buttons a#tumblr{
        background:#386082;
    }
    .share_buttons a#reddit{
        background:#c1c1c1;
        color:#333;
    }
    .share_buttons a#linkedin{
        background:#00649e;
    }
    .share_buttons a#pinterest{
        background:#e30000;
    }
    .share_buttons a#stumbleupon{
        background:#eb4924;
    }
    .share_buttons a#envelope{
        background:#65c093;
    }
```